# Query about forces felt by 2 moving charges

Tags: electromagnetism

A moving point charge can be thought of as a current. My understanding is that currents have associated magnetic fields. Let there be two charges that are moving parallel to each other with velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ and charges $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, respectively. What are the forces they feel? I understand they will feel the Coulomb force but won’t they also feel a force due to the magnetic fields associated with the individual charges?

Comment: *A moving point charge can be thought of as a current.* Not really, actually. They do have magnetic effects though (depending on your reference frame)

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Comment: A moving point charge is certainly a current *density* $\mathbf{J}=\rho\mathbf{v}$. Since you can integrate any current density over any surface, I don’t have a problem with also saying that it is a current, although obviously it is not a time-independent one.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, I suppose that is true.

Comment: Does that mean any 2 moving charges feel both a coloumb force and a force due to the magnetic field created by the other charges motion?